# How can I get separate digit image from a number image in android?

Tags: android, image-processing, machine-learning

I have a number Image in android like this.

[image]

I want to get every digit's image separately. like this-

zero: 
[image]

One:
[image]

Two:
[image]

Three:
[image]

Four:
[image]

I want to run some machine learning algorithm on this digit's image to detect the digits. How can I get this digit image from a number image in android?

Answer (score 2):

Read a book on image processing fundamentals. It will teach you everything you need to know (assuming you're already familiar with android development)

I'll tell you a simple approach:

First you want do a "segmentation" which will separate the digits from the paper.
Giving you a number of pixel clusters that belong together (your digits)
In this case a after converting the image to grayscale

[image]

we apply a global threshold using Otsu's method gives you:
[image]

Then you have to do something that is called "labeling" which will give you a list of pixel-groups that are connected. So called "blobs", "regions", "connected components" or similar. One or more of these connected regions close to each other will form a digit, but mostly you will have one region per digit.

Calculate the "bounding box" of that pixel cluster that belongs to one digit.

[image]

"Crop" the image region contained within the bounding box.

[image]

[image]

and so on...

You will find suitable tools in most image-processing libraries or you can simply code them yourself. Its rather trivial.

Just make sure you get a good basic understanding of image-processing befor you continue. It will make life much easier for all of us.